# How to get the all checkbox count on screen in SlickGrid?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

In Slick-grid, we have 3 check-boxes on the Header Row in 3 column, On-click of check boxes all the check-boxes in the column should checked. currently it is working fine but I need to get the count of all the checkboxes on the page, I mean in 3 columns and How many check-boxes checked overall and in each column?

E.g
Coumn 1 - 100 checkboxes
Column 2 - 25 checkboxes
Column 3 - 75 checkboxes

In total 200 check-boxes

First I need to get overall check-boxes count on the page.
Second how many check-boxes checked in each column?
Third - How many check-boxes checked in all the 3 columns?

Is there any code to get these details in Slick-grid?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<button onclick="countCheckBoxes()"> count</button>

<script>
function countCheckBoxes(){

var allCheckBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
var totalTrue = 0;
var totalFlase = 0;
for(i=0;i<allCheckBoxes.length;i++){

if(allCheckBoxes[i].checked){
totalTrue= totalTrue+1;
}else{
totalFlase=totalFlase+1;
}
}
console.log("total checked :"+totalTrue+" --- total unchecked "+totalFlase+"");
}

</script>
```

Comment: so in the console it shows how many checked and unchecked you can modify it to your need mark answer if you think it is answer otherwise I am happy to add more information @vinoth kumar

Comment: I didn't create It exactly as you described but you can modify it to suit your need but structure is what you wanter @vinoth kumar

Comment: good try, @Alireza Madad, but Slickgrid doesn't display all the rows at once - just the visible ones. So your code is more or less correct, but you'd need to use the data array that the SlickGrid values are based on. Assuming that these checkboxes are bound to an underlying value - vinoth kumar?

Comment: Are not shown cells have display:none; attributes or simply they dont exist on html cause idk what to do to them if they does not exist @Ben McIntyre

Comment: SlickGrid will not load all the checkboxes on page load. It will render virtually, so we cannot get all the checkboxes at one shot. it will load 15 checkboxes and onscroll, it will load another 15 checkboxes.

Comment: Yes Ben McIntyre you are correct. I have the data Array but onclick we can get only the clicked column data but how we can get the all the checkbox count and other columns checked checkbox count?

Comment: Based on the Checkbox count and checked checkbox count, we are doing some action to change the dropdown enable and disable.

Comment: As everyone pointed out it will only show current page selection and you need to remove 1 in your calculation when the "Select All" is checked (which will not happen every time). To add up to this, someone created this new [PR #542](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/542) that will address the selected rows on all pages (when using DataView)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the `6pac/SlickGrid` fork...

If you're using Slick.Grid object (without DataView) to get the data then you can just get the length of the selected rows

```js
var count = grid.getSelectedRows().length;
```

If you use Slick.DataView and you use Pagination then you could also use `grid.getSelectedRows()` but you'll get possibly unexpected result because it returns only current page selection. To counter that, you'll be able to use some new functions that are coming up to deal with such problem, coming from these [PR #542](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/542) and [PR #544](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/544) that are about to be merged (and eventually released in a new version). So assuming this is all released, you'll be able to do this with the new `getAllSelectedIds` function:

```js
var count = dataView.getAllSelectedIds().length;
```

I'm guessing that it only answers portion of your question, this won't give you how many grouped columns are checked, it will only give you how many item rows are checked.